# Solving $x^{\frac{2}{3}}-2x^{\frac{1}{3}}-3=0$

Tags: calculus

$$x^{\frac{2}{3}}-2x^{\frac{1}{3}}-3=0$$
I need some help solving this reducible to quadratic equation.

Comment: Have you tried to denote $y=x^{1/3}$ and get the equation $y^2-2y-3=0$?

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

Put $\;x^{1/3} = t.\quad$  Substitute; you'll have a quadratic in $t$. Solve for $t$, then solve for $x$.

ADDED help:

As suggested, we let $\;\bf t = x^{1/3}.\;$ Then $$\begin{align} x^{\large \frac{2}{3}}-2x^{\large \frac{1}{3}}-3= \left(x^{\large \frac{1}{3}}\right)^2 -2x^{\frac{1}{3}}-3=0 & \iff t^2 - 2t - 3 = 0 \\ \\ & \iff (t - 3)(t+1) = 0 \\ \\ & \iff t = 3 \;\text{ or } \;\; t = -1 \\ \\ & \iff {\bf t = x^{1/3}} = 3 \;\;\text{ or }\;\; {\bf t = x^{1/3}} = -1 \\ \\ &\iff x = (3)^3 \;\;\text{ or }\;\; x = (-1)^3 \\ \\ &\iff  x = 27 \;\;\text{ or }\;\; x = -1\end{align}$$

Comment: When I break it down I get X^2/3+=3; so do I just divide 2/3 by 3 to get my answer? and then the same for X^1/3?

Comment: @Mike Try again, that answer sounds wrong. Even if it were correct, that's not the right way to get back the value of $x$.

Comment: @amWhy: I wonder if the OP ever converged? +1